# python 3 list comprehension with if clause referring to list

Tags: python, list

I have this code:

```
xtralist = ["df","cvbcb","df"]
kont=[]
b = Counter(xtralist)
for item in xtralist:
    if item not in kont:
        print(b[item]
        kont.append(item)
```

The `kont` list is only there to see if the printing for that item has been done before. It works but is too slow for large `xtralist`, so I tried this:

```
[(print(b[item] and kont.append(item)) for item in xtralist if item not in kont]
```

which doesnt work. I am sure there are smarter ways, but how can I do this with list comprehension?

Comment: Perhaps your `kont` should be a set rather than a list. Sets are much faster for checking containment.

Comment: there also seems to be something wrong with your braces... also look up ternary operator to help you with your print statement

Comment: `and` is a logical operator so `print(b[item] and kont.append(item))` is trying to print a `bool`. Also, you shouldn't execute statements (like `print`) inside a list comprehension.

Comment: `if item not in kont:` will never be false, because you use a `Counter`, so there is no duplicate in it.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is enclose your `xtralist` into a `set` so that it doesn't have any duplicate elements, and then just `print` each item in the `set`:

```
xtralist = ["df", "cvbcb", "df"]
print('\n'.join(set(xtralist)))
```

> df
>   cvbcb

To dig into the code a little bit, check out each step:

```
>>> xtralist = ["df", "cvbcb", "df"]
>>> xtralist
['df', 'cvbcb', 'df']
>>> set(xtralist)
{'df', 'cvbcb'}
>>> '\n'.join(set(xtralist))
'df\ncvbcb'
>>> print('\n'.join(set(xtralist)))
df
cvbcb
```

However, note that a `set` is unordered, so if order is important, you'll have to iterate through your list; a little modification to what you were trying would work; you don't need a `Counter` at all:

```
xtralist = ["df", "cvbcb", "df"]
kont = []
for item in xtralist:
    if item not in kont:
        print(item)
        kont.append(item)
```

> df
>   cvbcb

Answer (score 0):

`set` is indeed the way to go. If the order is important though, you'll need to use a list and a set:

```
xtralist = ["df","cvbcb","df"]
already_seen = set()
for item in xtralist:
    if item not in already_seen:
        print(item)
        already_seen.add(item)
```

It outputs:

```
df
cvbcb
```

If you want to display the number of occurences, you can modify your code slightly:

```
from collections import Counter
xtralist = ["df","cvbcb","df"]
kont = set()
b = Counter(xtralist)
for item in xtralist:
    if item not in kont:
        print("%s * %d" % (item, b[item]))
        kont.add(item)
```

It outputs:

```
df * 2
cvbcb * 1
```